# Getting "Resource not accessible by integration" when accessing GitHub environment secrets via API

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I'm trying to list environment secrets in my GitHub repository using the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-environment-secrets). However, I consistently receive the following error:

```
Reference Environment Secrets:
{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#list-environment-secrets"
}
```

Here's the script I'm using:

```
jobs:
 check-secrets:
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest

 steps:
 - name: Checkout code
   uses: actions/checkout@v2

 - name: Compare Secrets Across Environments
   env:
     GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
   run: |
     # Fetch the repoId using the provided API
     repo_data=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}")
     echo "Repo Data:"
     echo "$repo_data" | jq .
     REPO_ID=$(echo "$repo_data" | jq -r '.id')

     # Fetch the environments
     env_data=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/environments")
     echo "Environment Data:"
     echo "$env_data" | jq .
    
     # Extract environment names
     env_list=($(echo "$env_data" | jq -r '.environments[] | .name'))

     # Use the first environment as a reference
     reference_env_secrets=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/repositories/$REPO_ID/environments/${env_list[0]}/secrets")
     echo "Reference Environment Secrets:"
     echo "$reference_env_secrets" | jq .
```

Has anyone encountered this before? How can I resolve this issue and successfully list the secrets?

Comment: These are protected, the GitHub Actions token doesn't have enough permissions to read the secrets. You'd need a PAT or OAuth token. A actions workflow can only access the secrets that are explicitly passed to it in the YAML.